# django modelformset_factory - management form data is missing

Tags: django, forms

I am still fighting with formsets and I cant really understand why I am getting this error:

u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Thats my code:
Please point out my mistakes and help me with resolving this issue.

```
@csrf_protect
@transaction.commit_on_success
def signup(request):
    form = NewUserCreationForm()
    doc_form = NewDocRegisterForm()

    SpecialityLicensesFormSet = modelformset_factory(SpecialityLicenses, extra=1, exclude = ('user'))
    formset = SpecialityLicensesFormSet(queryset=SpecialityLicenses.objects.none())

    if request.method == "POST":

        form = NewUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        doc_form = NewDocRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
        formset = SpecialityLicensesFormSet(request.POST or None)


        if form.is_valid() and doc_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

            user = form.save()

            doc = doc_form.save(commit=False)
            doc.user = user
            doc.save()



            print formset
            fset = formset.save(commit=False)

            for n in fset:
                n.user = user
                n.save()

            return HttpResponse("Uzytkownik utowrzony")

    return render_to_response("userena/signup_new.html", {'form': form,
                                                          'doc_form': doc_form,
                                                          'spec_form': formset,}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContex

t(request))
```

Template code:

```
<form action="/en/accounts/doc_register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}


    <div>
        {% if field.errors %}
            {{ field.errors|striptags }} |
        {% endif %}

        {{field.label}} | {{ field}}
    </div>


    {% endfor %}

    <hr>


    {% for f in doc_form %}
    <div>
    {% if f.errors %}
    {{f.errors|striptags}} | 
    {% endif %}

    {{f.label}} : {{ f }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr>

    {{ spec_form.management_form }}
    {{ spec_form }}

            <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: We need to see your template code as well.

Comment: `formset` in your view does not match `spec_form` in your template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you don't need to do `{{ formset.management_form }}` if you do `{{ formset }}`, just if you do

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
  {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

try removing the `{{ spec_form.management_form }}` bit from your template. Look at [the third example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates)

Comment: Lol, I just ran into this problem yesterday.  It was a little tricky to find it in the docs unless you read through the entire thing. (who has time for that?)

Answer (score 0):

add prefix for formset if prefix is missing for formset it will give error