# Management errors and __init__ errors trying to implement nested formsets

Tags: django

I am trying to add nested inlines using http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/

using these customizations for Django 1.4:

[django inline formsets with a complex model for the nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832672/django-inline-formsets-with-a-complex-model-for-the-nested-form/8286157#8286157) and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/E1oL0khsUlI

However, depending on the form.nested code, I get different errors.

Either :

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

or

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

**Code that explains it all is below:**

**forms.py **
yields this error

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

form.nested = [
         IndicatorValueFormSet(
              data=self.data or None,
              instance=instance,
              prefix = 'indicator_%s' % pk_value)]

IndicatorValueFormSet = modelformset_factory(IndicatorValue, extra=0)
IndicatorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Disease, Indicator, formset=BaseIndicatorFormSet, extra=1)
```

code below yields this error:

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

form.nested = [
          IndicatorValueFormSet(
               queryset = IndicatorValue.objects.filter(relevantindicator = pk_value), 
               prefix = 'value_%s' % pk_value)]

IndicatorValueFormSet = modelformset_factory(IndicatorValue, extra=0)
IndicatorFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Disease, Indicator, formset=BaseIndicatorFormSet, extra=1)
```

**models.py**

```
class Disease(models.Model):
        disease = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="disease")


class Indicator(models.Model):
        relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, verbose_name="disease")       
        indicator = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="indicator")

class IndicatorValue(models.Model):
        relevantindicator = models.ForeignKey(Indicator, verbose_name="indicators")
        indicator_value = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="indicator Values")
```

**Update**

**HTML**

```
 {{disease.management_form}}

 {{ indicators.management_form }}

{% for relevantindicator in indicators.forms %}

  {{ relevantindicator }}

  {% if relevantindicator.nested %}
  {% for formset in relevantindicator.nested %}
  {{ formset.as_table }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, Django adds data to your form for relating to managing the formset. You need to include it since you're rendering the form manually.

See: [django modelformset_factory - management form data is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303273/django-modelformset-factory-management-form-data-is-missing)

PS: A simple Google or Stack Overflow search would have yielded your answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure where the error is coming from. I believe my formsets are already in the HTML as per the resource your linked me to. I've updated the original question to include a snippet of my views and HTML.